# Configuration issue in nginx of docker - Troubleshooting docker with no instaces

Tags: bash, nginx, docker

When there was a configuration problem and docker instance is not coming up, how to do the troubleshooting ..

```
RajRajen:lb4b-my rajrajen$ docker run -d -t -i  -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name my_nginx_v4 my_nginx_v4
f459a9d666f1596dd77c1095b7256075b183fe8b7997c17e8f7b1640606bb075
RajRajen:lb4b-my rajrajen$ docker ps
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
RajRajen:lb4b-my rajrajen$ docker ps
```

Results in NO Result. How to identify the reason for the failure. There are many links if there is a running instance.

docker exec -ti  /bin/bash

Ref : https://askubuntu.com/questions/505506/how-to-get-bash-or-ssh-into-a-running-container-in-background-mode

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just gave a try to find whats in

When there was a configuration problem and docker instance is not coming up, how to do the troubleshooting ..

```
RajRajen:lb4b-my rajrajen$ docker log
5139b2417a39563a3848cc796b6c572d6508c0b862c4d13dceac9d59b3936420
```

And this log message is available

```
 RajRajen:lb4b-fe rajrajen$ docker logs  5139b2417a39563a3848cc796b6c572d6508c0b862c4d13dceac9d59b3936420
 2015/11/27 01:11:58 [emerg] 1#1: unknown "redir_match" variable
 nginx: [emerg] unknown "redir_match" variable
```

This hint helped to resolve the issue .

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Just gave a try to find whats in it.

When there was a configuration problem and docker instance is not coming up, how to do the troubleshooting ..

A) Identify the instance

```
RajRajen:lb4b-my rajrajen$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1a03bab01e40        lb4b-my       "tail -f /dev/null"   7 minutes ago       Excited(1)                            gc_lb4b-my
```

And this hidden container id helps to figure out further issue.

B) yet thats not enough to troubleshoot further issues inside the application

So, did the following to keep the docker running and then go inside the docker and execute the command that fails manually.

docker run -d -P --name gc_lb4b-my fe_lb4b-my tail -f /dev/null